# Measuring elapsed time in days

Tags: python, time

I would like to measure elapsed time in days with the Python time module. My attempt is:

```
import time, datetime

def elapsed_time(start)
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()-start).strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')

start = time.time()
print(elapsed_time(start))
# 1970-01-01-00-00-06
```

I would like the string to start from year 0, month 0, and day 0. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the difference between [`datetime.now()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) and your start timestamp. The resulting [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object has a `days` attribute:

```
from datetime import datetime

def elapsed_days(start):
    return (datetime.now() - start).days

start = datetime(2017, 11, 1)
>>> elapsed_days(start)
19

start = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
>>> elapsed_days(start)
323

>>> elapsed_days(datetime(1, 1, 1))
736652
```